# Take all ajaxed li's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Problem is that I cant find a way to take all `li.form-field` elements from ajax'ed content. Tried function `find` in many ways. I don't understand what is wrong.

For example I do this `console.log("fields", $(self.element)[0]);`

And I can see that the elements `.form-field` exists

[image]

but when I try to take them, it returns error.

```
console.log("fields", $(self.element)[0].find('.form-field'));
```

Comment: What about `$(self.element).find('.form-field')`?

Comment: @Pointy no still nothing lenght 0 here is the image of console.log https://imgur.com/HvblT1Z

Comment: Note that `$(self.element)[0]` is exactly `self.element`

Comment: You need to post your actual code **here**.

Comment: Maybe the elements don't exist when you try to get the elements. Ajax is asynchronous and you must make sure you try and get the elements after you create them. If you create them on the return of the ajax response then you need to access them in the promise resolve handler. Try the following and see how many `.form-field` elements exist: `(function(){var els=$(".form-field");debugger;})()`

Comment: @HMR You were right! Thank You. Post to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using something like jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you should access the element(s) after jQuery has finished it's request and set the dom:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  console.log("form fields:",this.querySelectorAll('.form-field').length);
});
```